# Block being rendered twice on a views page

Tags: views, blocks, search

I have created a view page '/searcher' which displays indexed results from `search_api_solr` queries - ajax is enabled for this view.  I have also created a custom block which will be used to display some information at the top of this page.

Issue: It appears when this page renders the block callback is being executed twice.  I have shared the code below - 'hello world' is `dpm()`'d twice. [image]I have tried other custom blocks from other custom modules, and it is doing the same thing. Anyone experienced something similar? Cheers

```
function my_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['date_range'] = array(
    'info' => t('Date Range - Top of Gant Chart'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, // default
  );
  $blocks['another_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Assemble the Crew'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, // default
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'date_range':
      $block['subject'] = t('');
      $block['content'] = my_module_date_range();
    break;

    case 'another_block':
      $block['subject'] = t('');
      $block['content'] = my_module_second_block_test();
    break;

  }
  return $block;
}

function my_module_date_range() {
  dpm('hello world');
}
```

Comment: Did you try to enable this block somewhere else other than above page you mentioned and check how many times you see message ?

Comment: Yes- I set it to appear on <front> and it only appears once. Very odd

Comment: Did you enable same block twice in above view page ? May be using module like context or some custom code ?

Comment: How did you enable the block on above page ?

Comment: Nope, I've checked the block page. It appears just once in the region: content.  It's strange, it only happens on this page- which is a view consisting of indexed results from search api solr.  I have two of these view pages and it experiences the same thing. Normal view pages of just content- the block only renders once correctly!

Comment: Can you try disabling Ajax in the view ?

Comment: Just tried! Still no luck!

Comment: Try debugging using devel and https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/ddebug_backtrace/7